# Fatal error wordpress xml importer

Tags: xml, wordpress, import

i am getting this error while importing xml file with wordpress xml importer

**Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 267029717 bytes) in C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\wordpress-importer\parsers.php on line 66**

Note : (size of xml is 250M , please do not suggest xml splitter)

Steps i tried

```
1 > php.ini        memory_limit=5000M                   (didnot workout)
2 > .htaccess      php_value memory_limit 5000M         (didnot workout 500 Error)
3 > wp-config.php  define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '5000M');  (didnot workout)
```

**Environment :**

Local server with XAMPP (latest).

any idea !

Comment: sorry no way you can do this ..until need a pc with huge ram or you have to split it

Comment: i tried also with 8GB ram , even intensive tasks i done with only 4 GB.there will be way.

Comment: instead of splitting .try to read the xml part by part

Comment: i think bro you didnt read all error statement : according to this in parshers.php allocation of memory is  same as XML file size , we need to increase via some way ,, thats all i need

Comment: well then sorry man ..you cant do that until you have that much amount of ram

Comment: that what we need to figure out, maybe some programmer only can tell us , how this file is allocating memory.